using submodules locally (git)
There just isn't any support in git for adding submodules that are on the local drive.
that is what I thought, but I was wrong. the submodules are just impossible to use.
I am using them to get local python packages available.
I'm in a repo called islandpk and I need the yoken package available
to me in 'src/yoken'.
Here is what I've tried:
git submodule add /Users/hecate/Applications/persephone-python-pac/src/yoken ./src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of '/Users/hecate/Applications/persephone-python-pac/src/yoken' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed

I know that git has trouble with protocol so I tried with 'file://'.
git submodule add file:///Users/hecate/Applications/persephone-python-pac/src/yoken ./src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of 'file:///Users/hecate/Applications/persephone-python-pac/src/yoken' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed

next I tried using a relative path:
git submodule add ../persephone-python-pac/src/yoken src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of '/Users/hecate/Applications/persephone-python-pac/src/yoken' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed

these are working tree repos that I've tried, so
I saved a bare version:
➜  islandpk git:(main)git submodule add file:///Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/ src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of 'file:///Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed
➜  islandpk git:(main)git submodule add /Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/ src/yoken 
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of '/Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed
➜  islandpk git:(main)git submodule add -- /Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/ src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed
fatal: clone of '/Users/hecate/.git-repos/yoken/' into submodule path '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken' failed

I thought that if I pushed to a
remote over ssh I would work better:
git submodule add ssh://xxxx:/home/rand_usr/.git-repos/yoken ./src/yoken
Cloning into '/Users/hecate/Applications/islandpk/src/yoken'...
rand_usr@xx.xx.x.xx's password: 
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
fatal: unable to checkout submodule 'src/yoken'



There just isn't any support in git for adding submodules that are on the local drive...

No, this is a general Git security setting.
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed

This is the default behavior for protocol.file.allow. By default file has a default policy of user.

user - protocol is only able to be used when GIT_PROTOCOL_FROM_USER is either unset or has a value of 1. This policy should be used when you want a protocol to be directly usable by the user but don’t want it used by commands which execute clone/fetch/push commands without user input, e.g. recursive submodule initialization.

Check your git config and GIT_PROTOCOL_FROM_USER environment variable.


I am using them to get local python packages available.

Submodules generally cause more problems than they solve. Often the problem can be solved with a more appropriate tool, usually a dependency manager. In this case, if you simply want your project to depend on a local Python repository, you should be able to use the Python dependency manager of your choice. They should all support fetching dependencies from a Git repository.
